# How to bound a difference between two statistical terms

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions, information-theory

coming from a computer science background and lacking some mathematical knowledge I got stuck trying to find bounds for the following difference:

$u - v = \sum_{i=1}^n k_i*logp_i - \sum_{i=1}^n k_i*logq_i$,
where $p_i, q_i$ are probability values such that $\sum_{i=1}^n p_i = \sum_{i=1}^n q_i = 1$, $k$ is a vector of samples with $k_i$ being an indicator of how often label $i$ (which occurs with probability $p_i$ **or** $q_i$) was drawn. Additionally we know the number of draws $r = \sum_{i=1}^n k_i$.

After doing some initial research it seems highly related to concepts like statistical difference but I can't quite find a way to apply it to my particular problem. Ideally I'd like to be able to show that there exists an a,b such that $ a\lt u - v \lt b$ (or at least one of them).

I'm thankful for any pointer or ideas!

Comment: $u-v$ is not bound. Consider for instance the case in which some $p_i$ (or $q_i$) is zero while $k_i$ is not.

Comment: in which case $u$ or $v$ become zero... how do I know from this that its not bound?

Comment: If $p_i \rightarrow 0$ and $k_i \neq 0$, then $k_i \log p_i \rightarrow -\infty$.

Comment: obviously you are right, must have been pretty tired to miss that one, thanks!